# Passing ArrayList to Ruby as a RubyArray

Tags: java, jruby

In Ruby, if you do something like

```
print ["Hello", 1, 2]
```

You get an output like

> ["Hello" , 1 , 2]

---

Have some `ArrayList` object, `list` in Java. It contains objects of type `Object`.

I am passing this list to my Ruby code. When you print this, the console outputs something like

```
<Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0x5ab077a7>
```

Which is correct, of course.

However, I would like to get the same behaviour as above. If `list` contains two objects of type `Object`, when Ruby pints it, I want to get

> [Object:0x1234567 , Object:0x21432423]

Rather than the reference of the list itself.

I suspect I should convert `list` to `RubyArray` before passing it to Ruby. But how?

Answer (score 2):

if you look at the API of `org.jruby.RubyArray` you'll find a `newArray` factory method :

```
java.util.ArrayList list = new java.util.ArrayList();
org.jruby.RubyArray array = org.jruby.RubyArray.newArray(runtime, list);
```

of course you need to have a reference to a `org.jruby.Ruby` `runtime` which from the Java side (depending on your usage scenario) might be obtained in a few ways :

```
org.jruby.Ruby.getGlobalRuntime();
org.jruby.Ruby.getThreadLocalRuntime();
```

also note, having a runtime instance there's several "helper" factory methods that create ruby objects in Java e.g. `org.jruby.Ruby.getGlobalRuntime().newArray(list)`